# What is the proper tool to take out the hook buried inside a garage spring

Tags: garage-door, stretching-spring

my garage door is broken and I found out that one end of the spring was broken. I can picture the moment that when it was happening, the spring bounced back to the other end where there is a iron hook, as a result, the hook was sucked deep into the spring, as you can see in the picture below. It struck there so deep that it can't be extracted with bare hands. Two solutions in my mind:

Solution#1: I dumped these two all together and buy new spring and hook;

Solution#2: find a right tool to extract the hook out of the spring.

In the 2nd solution, anyone can help to recommend some good extract tools exactly for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: Usually when these springs break there is no repair, use great caution these springs are dangerous when new.

Comment: If you can't stretch the spring to remove the eye-bolt, how would you stretch it to mount on the garage door?